# Identifying which elements on a page generate a cookie

Tags: cookies

Is there an easy way of working out which elements on a webpage will set a cookie? For example, if there are several adverts on a page, how would you work out which cookie is associated with which advert?

I'm using the Web Developer Toolbar in Firefox, and the View Cookie Information function provides a long list of all the cookies set by that particular page, but it doesn't tell you which section (or div) of the page the cookie has come from.  Does anyone know of any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, cookies are not related to any DOM elements.